# Scala: JavaFX Tableview

Tags: scala, javafx, tableview

My Code looks like this:

```
    // Example for the Product Entity
  @FXML var tableView: TableView[Product] = _
  @FXML var c1: TableColumn[Product,Integer] = _
  @FXML var c2: TableColumn[Product,String] = _
  @FXML var c3: TableColumn[Product,Double] = _



  //create data for inserting in an observerList
  val data: ObservableList[Product] = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    new Product(55,"hallo",33.0)
  )



  override def initialize(location: URL, resources: ResourceBundle): Unit = {
    //Für die columns namen setzen
    c1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory[Product,Integer]("id"))
    c2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory[Product,String]("name"))
    c3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory[Product,Double]("price"))

    //inserting data from the observableArrayList
    tableView.setItems(data)
  }
```

My question is, why I am getting always an NullPointerException here whenever I try to execute my JavaFX Program?
PS: The Product class should be fine. Could the reason be that I have used the

> java.sql

package and have written some functionality what Product should be able of?
PSS: The error with the NullPointerException occurs in this line:

```
tableView.setItems(data)
```

Edit:
This is what my FXML looks like =>

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorpane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="864.0" prefWidth="1267.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fhj.swengb.homework.dbtool.DbToolController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="tableview" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="43.0" prefHeight="629.0" prefWidth="800.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="c1" prefWidth="50" text="C1" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="c2" prefWidth="250" text="C2" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="c3" prefWidth="250" text="C3" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="687.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="190.0" text="Select Product" />
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="718.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="190.0" text="Select Customers" />
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="749.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="190.0" text="Select Orders" />
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="780.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="190.0" text="Select Order Positions" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Can you show the FXML where the table is defined?

Comment: @James_D sure just a moment
Edit: added it to the question!

Comment: Your `fx:id` does not match the variable name: you have `var tableView` but `fx:id="tableview"`.

Comment: oh wow yes that was the resulting error...
that happens when you code on your teammates code -.-